# What is "|>" in elixir?

Tags: elixir

What does `|>` stand for in elixir?

In this code examples extracted from code generated by Phoenix, it looks like the `var |> function_call(a,b,c)` syntax allows to call multiple functions passing `var` as argument, but I'm not completely understanding how does it work.

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.PostController do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :controller

  # ...

  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "post" => post_params}) do
    post = Repo.get!(Post, id)
    changeset = Post.changeset(post, post_params)

    case Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, post} ->
        render(conn, "show.json", post: post)
      {:error, changeset} ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(HelloPhoenix.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  # ...
end

defmodule HelloPhoenix.Post do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :model

  # ...

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the Pipeline operator. It takes the result of the left side and provides it as the first argument to the right side.

In practical terms, instead of doing

```
b = some(a)
c = another(b)
something_else(c)
```

or

```
something_else(another(some(a)))
```

You do

```
a
|> some
|> another
|> something_else
```

It is a better way to visualize the composition of a chain of functions.

For more info: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html#the-pipe-operator